# How add scrollview between two textviews

Tags: android, android-layout

My code is as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/title"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_name" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     ---------
     ---------
</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/space10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/copyright"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/copyright_text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I can see the above textview and imageview before scrollview, but not the bottom textview after scrollview. Is there any mistake in my code? Please help me out.

Comment: try to set the `layout_height` of your `ScrollView` to `0dp` and add `layout_weight="1"` to it.

Comment: @Aprian yeah..! that worked for me. thanx for the solution. You must have placed it as an answer, so that i could mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/title"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_name" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     ---------
     ---------
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/space10"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/copyright"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/copyright_text"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: just a small mistake. no need of weight in textview above scrollview. If placed occupies huge space. well edited the answer myself. thanx for the solution.

Comment: ohh.. sorry man,I placed it there first accidently. Forgot to remove that after correcting.